# Manage files (upload/download) in a MVC php app

Tags: php, file, security, model-view-controller

I'm working on a small project (following MVC pattern) that basically offers a protected page where each user can download some selected files (based on ownership decided by and admin user). These files are uploaded by an "admin" user. Users can see a list/download a file only if they are the owners, otherwise nothing is showed.

Now, I'm a bit worried about security and I don't knok which is the better way to implement it.

What's my idea.

- admin panel: a simple form that allow (multiple) file upload, store them somewhere and then save the paths into a db table.
- users page: after login, a function look into "stored-files" table in db for files owned by user. If any, get the paths and show them in a table/list. The users should be able to download them with a simple click on link.

First question: where should I save uploaded files? Are some path better than other?
Second: in this way every user should see a list of his files and a link to download them. But it is secure? Are there a better way to protect those file from unauthorized access?
Third: storing files. I want to make a directory for every user and there save user's file. Is this a good idea?

Any other tips or things to be careful?
Users cannot upload anything, they can only download them and this should avoid a lot of problems...

I hope it's clear :)

Thank you!

Comment: devfe, I've implemented something similar to what you're doing, but I'm not an expert, so I'll share here, in comments, and perhaps more expert persons could comment/answer.  My service accepts two requests (both GET requests):  a list of files that can be downloaded; and, a request to download a particular file.  When the list is presented, it shows a unique string for a file, not the path to the file.  If the user wants a file, they issue a GET request, where the line of the request contains the unique string and the header of the request contains a username and password.

Comment: And, I don't think that it matters where you store the files as long as it is not in /htdocs...that is, don't place in a directory that is accessible via browser (per your .htaccess settings).

Comment: Thanks @Craig ! Not sure if I understand your choice to show a unique string for each files... For each file you create an ID, then you show this ID instead of path and, to download file, users make a request with this ID, right? So you need to store the unique string with the path to file, am I right? Thank you!

Comment: Good question:  I do store the id (it could be in a db or a simple text file).  I hash the unique path to the file and that is the unique id that is presented to the user, e.g. /sample_folder/sample_file.txt is converted to 'jaosidr823ddku' using some php hash function, like base64.  When a request is made for file 'jaosidr823ddku', a search is made of the list of unqiue ids to find the corresponding path to the file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I lost this thread. Anyway, thanks for your advice! I made a unique string for each file and added one more check on username... It may be not perfect, but it should be reasonably safe for my needs. Thanks!